# ubuntu atom markdown preview won't display tables properly

Tags: markdown, atom-editor

I'm trying to make a table in Markdown and view it with Atom's Preview Markdown feature, but it doesn't seem to be working. How do I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tables work fine in Markdown preview when the syntax is correct. The problem in your code is that alignment of table cells, specifically the vertical lines.

It should look something like this:

```
|              | OCaml               | JavaScript           |
|--------------|---------------------|----------------------|
| numbers      | no longs or shorts  | has longs and shorts |
| empty values | called unit         | called null          |
```

This makes sense in multiple ways: the table is properly aligned in text-mode and will work in HTML preview. In other words, it follows the core philosphy of Markdown:

> Markdown is intended to be as easy-to-read and easy-to-write as is
>   feasible.
>
> Readability, however, is emphasized above all else. A
>   Markdown-formatted document should be publishable as-is, as plain
>   text, without looking like it’s been marked up with tags or formatting
>   instructions.
>
> *John Gruber, inventor of Markdown*

It's alright to be lazy, you can still follow the spec by using tools that make you life easier, e.g. Atom packages such as [markdown-table-editor](https://atom.io/packages/markdown-table-editor).

Comment: it seems that some markdown previewers (like github) will accept misaligned vertical lines and some won't. is there a way to make atom accept the misaligned version?

Comment: Actually, I've just noticed the preview works with misaligned tables as well, whether a that's bug or feature. Personally, I think it's a bad idea and against the philosophy or Markdown („Markdown is intended to be as easy-to-read and easy-to-write as is feasible.”) By misaligning the table, you lock out people who read Markdown in the Terminal or text editor. Don't expect other to use/read Markdown the same way you do. That said, there are [many packages for Atom](https://atom.io/packages/search?q=markdown+table) that make it easy to create perfectly aligned tables.

Comment: i'm not interested in the people who use vim to view markdown. right now i just want it to render properly. i was under the impression that the atom editor was capable of doing that, so i'm wondering if there's a config i'm missing somewhere

Comment: If you take a look at the package settings, you will see that there's no setting. Both, Atom and the GitHub website, use [GitHub flavoured Markdown (GfM) with the tables extension](https://github.github.com/gfm/#tables-extension) enabled.